# how to Portable Apps permanent file type association?

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive, file-association, portable-apps

I have windows 7 64bit.
I have many portable apps in my D Drive.

PROBLEM:

I was able to before, now I cannot associate my files (txt,docx,...any extension) to PortableApps[dot]com portable apps such as LibreOffice,Notepad2,... etc etc.

i did a lot of research, only portable apps from my 1st folder "PortableApps" are not working such as LibreOffice,Notepad2,...
But portable app my 2nd folder "portable_app" are working fine such as FastStone Image Viewer,foobar2000,...

Comment: did you do some research? what error message? try http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-files/windows-8-file-associations-problem/ee61f643-10d4-45c3-a7ac-395c68792d4d

Comment: i did a lot of research, only portable apps from my 1st folder "PortableApps" are not working such as LibreOffice,Notepad2,...
But portable app my 2nd folder "portable_app" are working fine such as FastStone Image Viewer,foobar2000,...

Comment: *Need Admin rights to edit.* To see associated fileType for extension do: `ASSOC .txt` (output `.txt=txtfile` Then to see associated program for this fileType do: `FTYPE txtfile` To reassociate this fileType to new program do: `FTYPE txtfile=notepad.exe %1 %*` NOTE: no quotes after `=`.  Try!

Comment: @befzz where to put this ASSOC .txt file??

Comment: into command line that running with admin previliges. google: `run cmd with administrator privileges` (basically Start - search `cmd.exe` - right click - Run with admin)  Short explain: Here **2** associations: **extension** <-> **file_type** and **file_type** <-> **program**

Comment: @befzz i don't understand i am mediocre at doing this DOS stuff, can you simplify and tell me what should i type in?
for example to associate ".srt" movie subtitle extension FROM Windows Notepad TO PortableApps Notepad2mod ???

Comment: did you tryed to do it at `Control Panel \ All Control Panel Items \ Default Programs \ Set Associations` ? (commands, posted before, doing similar things)